# C# MVC read value inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an Application in Asp.Net Core MVC6.

I have a Razor page that render dynamically object.

Assuming I have creating dynamically this two `Divs` in my page

```
 <div id="A1">
         <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
        <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
    </div>
    <div id="A2">
         <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
        <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
    </div>
<a href="#" onclick="Search()" class="nav-link px-4 py-4" title="Show All"></a>
```

When I call `Search()` function in javascript, I want to read the value inside each Div

```
function Search() {
-- to read value from Object
var SSN: $("#SearchSSN").val(),
}
```

But I want to read the value inside each Div

Something like

```
$("#A1").("#SearchSSN").val()
$("#A2").("#SearchSSN").val()
```

How can I Do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `Search()` Method like this

```
function Search() {
    var A1_SSN = $("#A1").find("#SearchSSN").val();
    var A1_LastName = $("#A1").find("#SearchLastName").val();

    var A2_SSN = $("#A2").find("#SearchSSN").val();
    var A2_LastName = $("#A2").find("#SearchLastName").val();

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all your divs using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to pull the values out into an array using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the input inside the div.

Here is an example that will just log the values to the console when you click 'Search'

```js
function Search() {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=A]');
  var values = [...divs].map((div) => div.querySelector('#SearchSSN').value)
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<div id="A1">
  <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
  <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
</div>
<div id="A2">
  <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
  <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
</div>
<div id="A3">
  <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
  <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
</div>
<div id="A4">
  <input type="text" id="SearchSSN" />
  <input type="text" id="SearchLastName" />
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="Search()" class="nav-link px-4 py-4" title="Show All">Show All</a>
```